# Python flask session not getting stored in generator function

Tags: python-3.x, session, flask

I am streaming output to the frontend using a generator in one of my flask routes and storing a value in a session variable like this:

```
@bp.route('/stream', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def stream():
    def generate():
        if request.method == "POST":
            ...
            ...
            # trying to store a variable to use in another function 
            session['testing'] = "testing"

    return Response(stream_with_context(generate()), mimetype='text/html')
```

I want to use this variable in another function like this:

```
@bp.route('/other_func', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def other_func():
    ...
    ...
    # trying to recieve it here 
    testing = session.get('testing')

    print(testing) # this value is 'None'
```

Any variable I store in the generator function results to `None`.

How can I get around this?

Comment: Do you have secret key set in your flask app config ?

Comment: @DinkoPehar yes, it's in my `init.py`, this used to work before, after adding the generator function it stopped working, does the generator function somehow affect the session from being stored?

Comment: what if you try `session.permanent = True` just before your `session['testing'] = "testing"` ?

Comment: Are you sure that generate function is executing that part in if statement ? Part request.method == 'POST' ?

Comment: I think this question can be bounty question. I think it has something to do with context managers and how they handle life expectancy of variable or how the context of `session` is lost. I don't know, maybe I'm wrong...

Comment: @DinkoPehar Yes, I'm sure that it is because my other parts of the code that is within the same scope are being executed (`yield`). Also , if i put a print statement there i see the print as well.

Comment: @Tobin Nope, that didn't work.

Comment: @DinkoPehar I think that's what it is too, since the generator doesn't store the values and just iterates through it once, I believe my session is getting cleared out after the function is done. Trying to think of a way around this...

Comment: I'll bookmark it if anyone gives a solution.

Comment: Add with app.app_context(): in your generator like this:

@bp.route('/stream', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def stream():
    def generate():
        with app.app_context():
            if request.method == "POST":
             ...

Answer (score 0):

Add with app.app_context(): in your generator like this:

```
@bp.route('/stream', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def stream():
    def generate():
        with app.app_context():
            if request.method == "POST":
             ...
```